# Constructing automata for regular languages

Tags: computer-science, automata

I have two languages:

1. $\{a^n b^m \mid n, m > 0, n - m = 0 \pmod 3\}$
2. $\{a^n b^m \mid n, m > 0, n + m = 0 \pmod 3\}$

and I'm having trouble drawing automata for them.

For the first language, I know that the first valid pairs are ab | aabb | aaaab | aaabbb, but I'm having trouble drawing that and putting it into a general automaton.

I know the for the second language, S ← abb|aab|aaabbb are the first valid pairs, but I again don't know how to put it into a general automaton.

q1:

[image]

Comment: You asked this same question two days ago and got an answer then. If you didn't understand the answer, post comments there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In question $1$, you can manipulate the equation a bit and get $n = m \pmod 3$. This isn't vital or very profound, but it may help your thinking.

For both of these, you can take different paths depending on the number of $a$'s you get. The first part that deals with $a$'s will always be the same. You should have three states $X$, $Y$, $YZ$ with the following property: if you're in state $X$, you just read a number of $a$'s congruent to $0 \pmod 3$, if you're in state $Y$, you just read a number of $a$'s congruent to $1 \pmod 3$, if you're in state $Z$, you just read a number of $a$'s congruent to $2 \pmod 3$.

I would make a closed loop of $3$ states for this part.

(Q: Which state should you start in?)

Then, what do you do when you're in one of $X, Y, Z$ and you read a $b$? You move to the next stage, where you find the number of $b$'s $\pmod 3$ and accept only if it matches the value for $a$.

Another closed loop would be appropriate here, since you might need to read an unbounded number of $b$'s. You'll need to rig things up so that you accept only the right thing.

(Hint: You can do this with $12$ states or $6$.)

Comment: Ahhh I'm still stumped, have no idea what to do, thanks for your answer though, did clear some things up

Comment: Where are you stumped -- any chance I can help further? (You don't need to accept my answer until it satisfies you.)

Comment: What do you mean by closed loop of 3 states? I have X -a-> Y -aa-> YZ

Comment: By a closed loop of 3 states I mean that as long as you keep reading $a$'s, you should be in one of states X, Y or Z. Not sure what that notation means -- what is YZ?

Comment: so do you mean like X -ab-> Y -aabb-> Z?  But I thought NFA's could only read one character at a time

Comment: You're correct, they can. That's why your notation is confusing to me -- you seem to be specifying multiply characters for a transition. Also, I didn't know you were making an NFA -- my answer is assuming you were doing a DFA. The same idea should apply.

Comment: The loop I'm talking about is just X goes to Y on an 'a', Y goes to Z on an 'a', Z goes to X on an 'a'

Comment: i think i understand and i made an edit to the original post, but how would I make sure only ab is accepted or only aabb is accepted?

Comment: Your drawing is good for the $a$'s. Now, on a $b$, leave that loop entirely and never come back. Create another loop that reads $b$'s and accepts when it gets the right number (which will depend on where you left the X-Y-Z loop).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30020/discussion-between-user270494-and-eli-rose).